# How to replace an input box with a dropdown in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace an input box with Vanilla JS. Currently I am using jquery to do this like so.

```
column.replaceWith("<select id='" + column[0].id + "' name='" + column[0].id + "' class='" + column[0].className + "'></select>");
```

I am refactoring all my code into Vanilla JS and this is the last thing I need to do. I have done the document.createElement('select'); and that creates the `<select></select>` element. I then tried to do;

```
newEl.innerHTML += '<select id="selBidReceivedIsPM" name="selBidReceivedIsPM">'
                + '<option value="0">AM</option>'
                + '<option value="1">PM</option>';
```

,
but this doesn't create the id or name. I've been googling and trying things for the last 3 hours and need some help figuring this out.

html:

```
 <label for="columnA5"></label>
 <input
       type="number"
       id="columnA5"
       name="columnA5"
       class="columnA"
       step="any"
 >
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML and full script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work to create select with options having value and innerHTML.

```js
var select = document.createElement('select');
select.id="selBidReceivedIsPM" 
select.name="selBidReceivedIsPM"
var val=2;
var time=["AM","PM"];
for (var i = 0; i<val; i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = time[i];
    select.appendChild(opt);
}
console.log(select)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, if `DOM` element is not created by `javascript` but rendered You can't "delete" it (in Your case `input type="number"...`).

You can "replace" it by "hiding" `input` and place `select` element on "his" place.

There is example, try it :

```js
function replaceEle() {
  var txt=document.getElementById('columnA5');
  /*
   or You can use querySelectorAll :
   var txt=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
   then You'll get all textboxes in page, and then You have to use for loop
  */
  var sel=document.createElement('select'); //create select element
  sel.id='selBidReceivedIsPM';
  sel.setAttribute('onchange','alert(this.value)'); 
  /*show selected value, or instead alert You can type some JS
    function, what gonna do when option is changed */
  var opt=document.createElement('option'); //create option element
  opt.value=0;opt.innerHTML='AM';
  sel.appendChild(opt); //add option element into select element
  opt=document.createElement('option');
  opt.value=1; opt.innerHTML='PM';
  sel.appendChild(opt);
  sel.selectedIndex=0; //set default selected value
  txt.style.display='none'; //hide input element
  txt.parentNode.insertBefore(sel, txt); //insert select element just before input, 
  
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="columnA5" value=""/><br>
<input type="button" value="Replace it" onclick="replaceEle();"/>
```